# Modelling the zero-inflation parameter in a ZIP regression model

Tags: regression, zero-inflation

I have data from two agricultural experiments, one on 101 sites, the other on 97 sites.

In both experiments, the response variable, $Y$, is a count, with an excess of zeros and there is a binary covariate, $I$, which indicates whether the site received a particular treatment.

In the first experiment these data were successfully modelled with a zero inflated Poisson (ZIP) model, providing estmates for the probability of zero, $\phi$, such that $\phi=0$ would correspond to an ordinary Poisson model, and for the treatment effect.

However, in the second experiment there is also a continuous covariate, $I$, which is associated with $\phi$.

How can I model these data so that I can estimate the association between $\phi$ and $X$, and also treatment effect ?

Comment: What software are you using? (Note that questions strictly about software will be migrated to StackOverflow).

Comment: @PeterFlom I have access to R, Stata and MPlus.

Comment: Does [this](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/pscl/html/zeroinfl.html) answer your question? If not, please clarify

Comment: @PeterFlom , it certainly looks like it does, thanks  :-)

Comment: Note that in the question you used the same name $I$ twice, for two different variables ...